# SoupUI and groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

We are using `soupUI` to perform load test on REST webservices, We have one testcase that accepts 3 parameters. Since we aren't using soupUI pro we are writing groovy to read textfile and send parameters to REST service. When groovy script ran it works fine and when we run testcase parameters are not passed. below is the groovy script.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
def size
File fileValues = new File("C:/Input.txt")
List lines=fileValues.readLines()
size = lines.size.toInteger()
propTestStep = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("looper-props")
for( counter in 0..size-1) 
{
    tempValue = lines[counter]
    inputValues=[]
    inputValues=tempValue.split(",")
    userName= inputValues[0]
    workSpaceName= inputValues[1]
    productId= inputValues[2]
    iteration=inputValues[3]
    propTestStep.setPropertyValue("userName", userName)
    propTestStep.setPropertyValue("workSpaceName", workSpaceName)
    propTestStep.setPropertyValue("prdAreaId", productId)   
    propTestStep.setPropertyValue("count", iteration)
    testRunner.runTestStepByName("workSpace") 
}
```

And have created properties `userName`, `workSpaceName`, `prdAreaId` and `count`. How to pass these properties to rest request?

Comment: You're setting properties on `looper-props`, but then running `workSpace`...  Is this right?  Also, but unrelated, your code can be [shortened to this](https://gist.github.com/timyates/847b911843eb586e92a5#file-shorter-groovy)

Comment: @tim_yates it seems the `looper-props` is a properties step which is designed to hold properties and their values. Also, I think you may be closer to the answer than you think. The `workspace` step will not have the properties if there isn't a properties transfer step which will take the properties from `looper-props` step and set them at a level(project, test suite, test case) level which is accessible to the `workspace` step.

Comment: Thanks for the replies but I am sorry, I am totally new to soupUI, I am actually trying to create loadtests. One thing I realized is when we run through load run screen, it runs groovy script every time a new thread is created. I know it is not good asking some one to do this for me but please share logic or some information including how can I pass those parameter to the request i'm trying to execute

Comment: how are you running the load test? using soapUI or loadUI? Basically you have a flow where you read data, set data, run test step..and you want to load test this flow?

Comment: I am running through soapUI. I've a REST request, I've one text file which contains parameter. I read line by line and split each line and assign them to property and now i want those property values to be transferred to REST request. And I've created a load test. When I click on load test, it opens where i can mention number of threads to be run. What is the actual process to do it? I want to run from load test screen because  i need reports. I have flow in load test..groovy script reading file...properties and lastly the request to be run. Thanks in advance

Comment: I can give you a general approach/sample to implement this but it will be using one of the publicly available Web Services probably wouldn't be REST. Will that work for you? Also what does your property/data file look like?

Comment: Could you please update your question? `soapUI and groovy` is not a clear enough title and will not be helpful for others who come here looking for answer to the same problem as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i may have an approach that may work for you.

It is my understanding that you want to run a load test in soapUI of a rest service. In your test case, you are reading a text file(comma separated), setting the property values and running the rest test request.

I have created a Test Suite that demonstrate what you want to do. For the purpose of this demo i have made use of the [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) [free webservice which returns a Json response](http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?). If you want to run my test suite i would suggest that you create your own username.

The text file looks like this. (notice i have no header row)

```
44.1,-22.4,55.2,-9.9, fr, demo
44.1,-22.4,55.2,-9.9,en, demo
44.1,-22.4,55.2,-9.9,de, demo
44.1,-22.4,55.2,-9.9,en, demo
```

I am using a method described at [Mike Swooeeney](https://www.blogger.com/profile/11363715070080347278)'s [blog post](http://testautomationnoob.blogspot.ru/2012/10/soapui-data-looping-with-groovy-script.html).

My test Suite has the below structure

```
-Test Suite
    -Test Case
        -Rest Test Request
        -readNextLine Groovy step
```

At the test suite level i have the following properties.
[image: test suite level properties]

In the test case setup script i am reading first row and assigning it to test suite level properties. The code for that is...

```
def fPath = context.expand('${#TestSuite#TestDataFilePath}')

//Create a new filereader object, using the context variable so it can be used between test components
context.fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fPath))

//Read in the first line of the data file
firstLine = context.fileReader.readLine()

//Split the first line into a string array and assign the array elements to various test case properties
String[] propData = firstLine.split(",")
testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("north",propData[0])
testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("east",propData[1])
testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("west",propData[2])
testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("south",propData[3])
testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("lang",propData[4])
testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("username",propData[5])

log.info "Read data north=${propData[0]};east=${propData[1]};west=${propData[2]};south=${propData[3]};language=${propData[4]};username=${propData[5]}"
```

I am directly accessing these properties in my test request, which look like this..
[image: Rest Test Request Properties]

The last step (***must be the last step***) i am reading the next line and setting it to test suite level properties and then moving control to the first step in the test case. The code for that is...

```
/*Read in the next line of the file
  We can use the same fileReader created in the Setup script because it
  was assigned to the context variable.*/

nextLine = context.fileReader.readLine()

/*If the end of the file hasn't been reached (nextLine does NOT equal null)
  split the line and assign new property values and go back to the first 
  test request step*/

if(nextLine != null){
    String[] propData = nextLine.split(",")
    curTSuite = testRunner.testCase.testSuite
    curTSuite.setPropertyValue("north",propData[0])
    curTSuite.setPropertyValue("east",propData[1])
    curTSuite.setPropertyValue("west",propData[2])
    curTSuite.setPropertyValue("south",propData[3])
    curTSuite.setPropertyValue("lang",propData[4])
    curTSuite.setPropertyValue("username",propData[5])
    log.info "Read data north=${propData[0]};east=${propData[1]};west=${propData[2]};south=${propData[3]};language=${propData[4]};username=${propData[5]}"
    testRunner.gotoStep(0)
}
```

Finally, In the test case teardown script i am closing the file reader. The code for that is...

```
context.fileReader.close()

log.info "file closed"
```

I have created a load test for this test case and run it using Simple Strategy for 10 seconds with 5 threads and a delay of 1000 miliSecond with a random of 0.5. Below is a screen grab of load test run metrics.
[image: Load Test Run Numbers]

I am also printing the properties being used so below is the data usage pattern.

```
Thu Apr 10 20:50:26 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:26 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:26 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:26 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:26 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:32 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:32 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:32 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:32 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:32 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:32 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:32 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:33 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:34 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:34 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:34 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:34 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:34 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:34 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:34 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:34 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:34 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:34 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:34 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:35 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language= fr;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:36 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:37 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:37 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:37 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:37 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
Thu Apr 10 20:50:37 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:37 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=de;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:37 ADT 2014:INFO:Read data north=44.1;east=-22.4;west=55.2;south=-9.9;language=en;username= demo
Thu Apr 10 20:50:37 ADT 2014:INFO:file closed
```

Lastly, I want to know why you want to use soapUI for load testing. Although it has the load testing functionality but it is absolutely the wrong tool for that. Have a look at JMeter, loadrunner or other performance testing tool.

My test suite is [available at Mega.co.nz](https://mega.co.nz/#F!DtxgkQIQ!gr1_lQdeykFtERX7k4iFTA)

Hope this helps.

**Remember** to do a virus scan on the downloaded files before using them.

Comment: Thanks a log Abhishek ! Yes I realized as soon I observed soupUI reads files every time I run my load test (For each and every virtual user). If I read all at once and create threads then results would not be appropriate as i expect them. Thanks a lot Abhishek I understood what you mentioned.

Comment: There is another way to do this..similar to how you were doing it. In that approach everything in the test case is controlled from the groovy script and you wouldn't have create threads. You need to worry about threads if you want to simulate a load that cannot be generated using soapUI's built in strategy. Also, if my answer works for you would you mind accepting it?

Comment: THanks Abhishek, Sorry I was supposed to accept your answer on day one since i was on vacation could not do it. Thanks a lot and I've started creating tests in Jmeter instead of this too as i want to do only load test not functional tests.

Comment: Not a problem buddy. Vacations are important too :) Feel free to ask questions about JMeter too.

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI is a functional testing tool.   Are you certain you don't mean LoadUI?

Comment: Unfortunately, soapUI can also be used to run load tests.